# I want my MVC application to be a website

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Visual studio creates an asp.net MVC application as a project I want it to be created like an asp.net website, will it give me problems if I force it to do so by creating all the folder and references manually?

Comment: If you want a web-site why wouldn't you just create that kind of project in the first place? Why are you even trying to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys but I found the solution at http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/08/15/How-To-Use-ASPNET-MVC-in-Website-rather-than-Web-Application-Project.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It likely won't work at all.

You can just add code-behind files to your views, but that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually [possible](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/08/15/How-To-Use-ASPNET-MVC-in-Website-rather-than-Web-Application-Project.aspx) with the Preview 4 release, but I've never tried it with the RTM 1.0 release.

IMO if you create the project structure manually it should work but don't forget that you won't get any shortcuts for adding controllers, views, ... You will have to do everything manually.

Oh, and if you want to unit test your controllers you will have to put them into a separate assembly.

Comment: I tried it manually, but at RUNTIME then it keeps saying "The controller for path '/Bezaat.WebUI' could not be found or it does not implement IController"

Even though every thing is identical ! any ideas ?

Comment: Where is your controller located? Don't forget to put it in the special App_Code folder or in a separate assembly otherwise it won't be compiled.

Comment: I've just tried ASP.NET MVC in a web site project and it worked nice.